# How do i import shapefiles in bulk to mssqlserver using msscmd tool

Tags: gis, shapefile

I'm trying to bulk import shapefiles using `msscmd` tool, when I use

```
c:> msscmd -server=msserver -db=mydb -table=mytable -import=shp -shp_filename="C:\path\to\shapefileszaf\*.shp "
```

it gives me [image: an error].

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileI0Permission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
   at System. Security. Permissions. FilelOPermission .AddPathList(FilelOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDupli cates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileI0Permission..ctor(FileI0PermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boo lean needFullPath) 
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) 
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromPro xy) 
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) 
   at SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile.ParseHeader() 
   at SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile..ctor(String filename, Boolean fileBasedlndex) at StoredProcedures.ImportFromShapefileMain(String shapefile, String schema_name, String table_name, String column_name, Int32 srid, String type, String connectionSt ring, Int32& importedRows, TimeSpan& elapsedTime) 
   at MsSqlSpatialConsole.Program.ImportShp(ArgParser arg, String schema, String table, String column, Int32 srid, String type, String connectionString) 
   at MsSqlSpatialConsole.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Anyone with an idea or a tool I can use to make it import all shape files in the directory?

Comment: A guess: your quoted -shp_filename value has an embedded space at the end: "C:\path\to\shapefileszaf\*.shp " One might also guess that that argument does not accept wildcards; in which case you may need to write a cmd file loop that will do them one by one.